# How do I get rid of the ".html" in the url of my webpages?

Tags: html, url

For example, on my contact page, the url reads: websitename/contact.html. If possible, I'd like to change the website path to websitename/contact.

Comment: It depends on the HTTP server you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this on your .htaccess file

```
    #mode_rerwrite start here
    RewriteEngine On 
    # does not apply to existing directores, meaning that if the folder exists on server then don't change anything and don't run the rule.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    #Check for file in directory with .html extension 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    #Here we actually show the page that has .html extension
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC, L]
```

Comment: I'm not really good at explaining but I added comments on what the lines are for.

Comment: Thank you for the update! As for your ability to explain, that's something you'll learn with practice; and, honestly: your explanations here - while brief - don't really support your claim that you're not 'good' at them :)

Comment: What .htaccess file? Nothing in the question suggests the OP is using an HTTP server which supports htaccess.

Comment: [You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)